# remove quotes from url in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, url

I am trying to remove a double quotes from a URL but I am unable to remove it

I tried the following code and more things but I am not able to remove the double quotes from the url. Could you please help me on how to remove the double quotes from url.

Also the url is something like this and the same gets reflected in sample.out, this is the url that comes from an application

```
"https://dummy.com:443/en.server/html/next/index.jsp?dl=dash&envId=00001&planId=0001&Monitoring=false&FilterId=01&Start=1527782791576&End=1528387591576"
```

The FreeText in the does not get the url without quotes. I want the FreeText to have the url without quotes.

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "PPI=C:\PPI"
echo "%AnalysisDeepLink%" >> E:\sample.out
set "ADL=%AnalysisDeepLink%"
rem set ADL1=!ADL:~1,-1!
rem echo.%ADL1%

rem set ADL=%ADL:"=%
rem echo %ADL%


rem for /f "useback tokens=*" %%a in ('%ADL%') do set str=%%~a
rem echo.%ADL%

echo %ADL% >> E:\sample.out

"%PPI%\ppi.exe" -c "%PPI%\ppi4vce.conf" -e "Domain=dummy;OriginSeverity=MAJOR;FreeText=%ADL%"  -w "%PPI"
```

Comment: You have the set command that removes the first and last characters commented out.  It will not run with the REM there. It should be: `set "ADL1=!ADL:~1,-1!"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Squashman I did try that as well but did not get success. The reason why I put that rem because so as to tell that I did try that option as well. Is there any example that you can give which I can follow

Comment: Before you can remove the outer double quotes you have to escape every char otherwise being interpreted by cmd.exe like the `&` with a caret. `^&`

Comment: You didn't put quotes around the set command to protect special characters like in my example.

Comment: Or: `for %%U in (%ADL%) do set "ADL=%%~U"`